# ApplicationScoped bean not injected in JSF 2.3 FacesConverter

Tags: cdi, converters, jsf-2.3

I have following FacesConverter:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Onderwerp.class, managed = true)
public class OnderwerpConverter implements Converter<Onderwerp> {

@Inject
private Web web;

@Override
public Onderwerp getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {

    log.trace("Converting to object from string: " + value);

    return web.getAllActiveOnderwerpen().stream().filter(o -> o.getId().equals(Long.parseLong(value))).findFirst().get();
}


@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Onderwerp onderwerp) {

    log.trace("Converting to string from object: " + onderwerp);

    return onderwerp.getId().toString();
}

}
```

The referenced CDI bean is:

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class Web { ... }
```

Faces-config.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd" version="2.3">
```

Now whatever kind of bean I inject via @Inject it is always null. It seems the injection feature in 2.3 is not working (yet), or I am missing something :)

I'm using Mojarra 2.3.0 on EAP 7.0. Also tested without success using 2.3.3 on EAP 7.0 and 7.1.

My current workaround is replacing the code where I need the injected CDI bean like this:

```
return CDI.current().select(Web.class).get().getAllActiveOnderwerpen().stream().filter(o -> o.getId().equals(Long.parseLong(value))).findFirst().get();
```

This works fine, but is kinda ugly of course :)

Anyone has experienced this behavior?

Comment: Is the converter recognized as a bean so that it is injected into? Try adding some bean defining annotation to it, such as `@Dependent` or `@Named` or whatever else fits your setup.

Comment: In JSF 2.3 you can add managed=true and it automatically should recognize CDI beans... But it doesn't. I can add some bean defining annotation and it works, but that is the old workaround pre 2.3, so no point then.

Comment: Meaning the workaround doesn't help anymore? BTW do you have any other CDI beans in your application so you can verify that CDI in general is working? Maybe also double check the presence of `beans.xml` (and try using bean discovery mode `all`).

Comment: @Siliarus All workarounds work ;) I have plenty of CDI beans which are injected into eachother, mixed with EJB beans. No issues there. I don't have beans. xml, because I choose to use only annotated CDI beans. I could add it and put discovery mode all, but the whole point is I want the native CDI support in `@FacesConverter` introduced in JSF 2.3. I need somebody who also has 2.3 installed in his application server who can confirm (or deny) this behavior. Thanks already for helping.

Comment: created an issue at mojarra 2.3 https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4308

Comment: I confirm this and I have the same problem with WildFly 16.0 JSF 2.3 @FabiYo

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I foud the solution.

You must create a config bean indicating JSF version:

```
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig;
import javax.faces.annotation.FacesConfig.Version;


@FacesConfig(
        // Activates CDI build-in beans
        version=Version.JSF_2_3 
        )
public class ConfigBean {

}
```

Comment: Not working, see https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4308

Comment: @FabiYo: did you try? Since for some it seems to do things

Comment: I'll try to summarize all we've to  do in order to make it work.
 1 - Set managed = true in "@FacesConverter" annotation
 2 - Verify faces 2.3 version in faces-config.xml
 3 - Create "@FacesConfig" annotated config bean with property "version=Version.JSF_2_3" 

Regarding @FabiYo example, I think the problem can be related to "@ApplicationScoped" annotation in Config bean.

Comment: @Kukeltje, sure, that is why I logged the issue. For some it is working, because they use another application server or a servlet container

Comment: @JesúsIbánFernándezRodríguez please provide full server config, versions of JSF etc...

Comment: But then **always** mention your environment specs

Comment: @FabiYo
WildFly Full 15.0.1.Final
Mojarra 2.3.5.SP2
JSF 2.3